# Valgrind and misuse of new[]?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

Valgrind is throwing a bunch of errors concerning the new[] operator in my program. I condensed it to a smaller example below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <omp.h>

int num_spline_pts = 90;

double *initialize_TriSol_a();
double *initialize_TriSol_b();

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    double *a = initialize_TriSol_a(); 
    double *b = initialize_TriSol_b();

    return 0;
}

double *initialize_TriSol_a(){
    double *a = new double[num_spline_pts]; //Valgrind does not like
    double *b = new double[num_spline_pts]; //Valgrind does not like

    for (int i = 0; i < num_spline_pts; i++){
        a[i] = 1;
        b[i] = 4;
    }

    *a /= *b;
    for(int i=1;i<num_spline_pts-1;i++)
    {
        b[i] -= (a[i-1]);
        a[i] /=b[i]; 
    }

    return &a[0];
}

double *initialize_TriSol_b(){
    double *a = new double[num_spline_pts]; //Valgrind does not like
    double *b = new double[num_spline_pts]; //Valgrind does not like

    for (int i = 0; i < num_spline_pts; i++){
        a[i] = 1;
        b[i] = 4;
    }

    *a /= *b;
    for(int i=1;i<num_spline_pts-1;i++)
    {
        b[i] -= (a[i-1]);
        a[i] /=b[i]; 
    }
    b[num_spline_pts-1] -= a[num_spline_pts-2]; 
    return &b[0];
}
```

To explain, in the code I have to solve some tridiagonal systems repeatedly. However, some of the vectors used in the forward and backward sweeps don't change from one matrix to the other so I pre-calculate them here. This program will compile and I can use the resulting vectors a,b as desired in main. However, valgrind returns errors

```
==32039== 720 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 5
==32039==    at 0x4A0674C: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:305)
==32039==    by 0x400727: initialize_TriSol_a() (test.cpp:22)
==32039==    by 0x4006F7: main (test.cpp:15)
==32039== 
==32039== 720 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 5
==32039==    at 0x4A0674C: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:305)
==32039==    by 0x40073F: initialize_TriSol_a() (test.cpp:23)
==32039==    by 0x4006F7: main (test.cpp:15)
==32039== 
==32039== 720 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 5
==32039==    at 0x4A0674C: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:305)
==32039==    by 0x40086C: initialize_TriSol_b() (test.cpp:41)
==32039==    by 0x400700: main (test.cpp:16)
==32039== 
==32039== 720 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 5
==32039==    at 0x4A0674C: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:305)
==32039==    by 0x400884: initialize_TriSol_b() (test.cpp:42)
==32039==    by 0x400700: main (test.cpp:16)
```

These are referring to where I used the new double[num_spline_pts] operator in the above code. From trying to google around to look for similar problems it sounds like the issue might be because is there isn't a delete[] happening. But these are not temporary arrays, I keep using these again and again. I'm further confused because in my real code (not this test example) I use new[] else where in a similar fashion and valgrind does not complain about it (i.e. it is data that is continually updated so I never end up using delete[]).

Am I really mis-using new[] here? Or is valgrind just complaining about the potential for abuse?

*EDIT*
Okay, I definitely see how I was failing to delete a and b in the respective functions that return a and b. However, in main, I use a and b through out the program. I guess my question now is, is it correct usage to delete every single variable and array created. i.e. should the end of main() always consist of a bunch of deletes? I just feel like I haven't seen this in other peoples code.

Comment: You're not freeing `b`. On top of that you're not freeing anything at higher levels either. Use standard library containers such as `std::vector` to avoid such problems.

Comment: Is there any use of `new[]` besides implementing `std::vector` that is not misuse?

Comment: **EDIT:** You should not be dynamically allocating everything to begin with. Mostly you should put your data into containers like `std::vector` so you don't need to delete it.

Comment: @Galik let's say I'm stubborn and want to do it with arrays, then would one have a series of delete[]/house keeping section at the end of main()?

Comment: @Fractal20 If your arrays are going to be fixed length then you don't need to allocate them with `new` so they wouldn't need deleting. Otherwise you can put them in a smart pointer such as [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). Then you don't need to `delete[]` them. But you can always fix it so you have tonnes of stuff to `delete` at the end of `main()` if you really want to! ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `delete[]` your arrays when you finished with them.

For example:

```
double *initialize_TriSol_b(){
    double *a = new double[num_spline_pts]; //Valgrind does not like
    double *b = new double[num_spline_pts]; //Valgrind does not like

    for (int i = 0; i < num_spline_pts; i++){
        a[i] = 1;
        b[i] = 4;
    }

    *a /= *b;
    for(int i=1;i<num_spline_pts-1;i++)
    {
        b[i] -= (a[i-1]);
        a[i] /=b[i]; 
    }
    b[num_spline_pts-1] -= a[num_spline_pts-2]; 

    // what about a?
    return &b[0];
}
```

At the end of that function you return the pointer `b` (in a roundabout way) but `a` goes out of scope and you didn't `delete[]` it.

And here:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    double *a = initialize_TriSol_a(); 
    double *b = initialize_TriSol_b();

    // what about delet[] a; ?
    // what about delet[] b; ?
    return 0;
}
```

You need to `delete[]` your arrays when you finish with them.

**NOTE:**

Ideally in modern `C++` you should avoid making raw allocations using `new` and/or use smart pointers so that you don't have to call `delete`.

Best of all consider storing your data in a *container* such as an [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Best to recommend avoiding raw pointers _entirely_. There's very little need for them nowadays.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree but there are so many alternatives in this example. It could just declare automatic arrays because - fixed length. Then I could recommend `std::array`. But depending on where they are going with this they may want variable length arrays after all so -`std::vector`? And most likely this is an assignment designed for learning pointers and new/delete (because many courses teach C++ backwards.). However, I'll mention something about avoiding raw allocations.

Comment: One should _start_ with `array` & `vector` and then move to `new[]`/`delete[]` only when strictly necessary, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

Your use of `new[]` is correct. Valgrind is complaining about memory leaks, not invalid memory access.

You need a matching call to `delete[]` to fix those.

I recommend you use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead. You could also use smart pointer `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` to take care of memory management.

Answer (score 2):

Error states that `720 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost`, not misuse of new[]
You are not calling delete[] and there is a memory leak, and that is why valgrind is complaining.

Remember to always release memory (preferably - use `std::unique_ptr` in C++11 so it will happen 'automatically'). Probably standard `std::vector<double>` would be what you really need.

Comment: Additionally, you may wish to read up on the RAII idiom. Making all your resources allocate their memory on construction and deallocate them on destruction will reduce a great many headaches in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you fail to deallocate what you've allocated with `new[]`. In order to fix this, you need to add `delete[] b` in both functions, and also call `delete[]` on the pointers received inside `main` after you are done with them:

```
double *initialize_TriSol_a(){
    double *a = new double[num_spline_pts];
    double *b = new double[num_spline_pts];
    ...
    delete[] b; // <<== Add this
    return a; // No need to use &a[0]
}
...
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    double *a = initialize_TriSol_a(); 
    double *b = initialize_TriSol_b();
    ... // Do things with a and b
    delete[] a; // <<== Add this
    delete[] b; // <<== Add this
    return 0;
}
```

A much better approach would be using `vector<double>`, because it would let you avoid manual memory management in the first place.

Comment: Some people downvote out of spite I guess. Noticed a lot of trolls around over the last few days.

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind detects memory leaks. That's when you allocate memory and never de-allocate it, which is precisely what you're doing here.

Use a vector.